# What is different between the two ways to define the Private member variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The first way.

```
//Myclass.m
@implementation Myclass{
    NSString * name;
}
-(void) print{
    NSLog(@"%@",name);
}
@end
```

The second way.

```
//Myclass.m
@interface Myclass()
@property(nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation Myclass
-(void) print{

    NSLog(@"%@",_name);
}
@end
```

Why can't to access 'name' by 'self.name' in the first way but can use 'self.name' and '_name' in the second way. What is different between the two ways.

I confused by this because i want override the 'isEqual' method , the first way can't access the other object's private member variable but the second way can use '.' to access.

Forgive my English.

Comment: Note: The question was substantially changed after the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use neither of these. I'd always just use the property...

```
//Myclass.m
@interface Myclass()
@property(nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation Myclass

-(void) print{
    NSLog(@"%@",_name);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.name);
}

@end
```

Properties are synthesised into iVars with getter and setter methods. The iVar is always called _propertyName.

Using a property allows you to fine tune the ARC properties of that more easily than with iVars (IMO anyway).

Answer (score 1):

When compiler will see a @property it will generate a setter and a getter (depending on annotations added to the property). So in the first example compiler adds two methods:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
...
}

- (NSString *)name {
...
}
```

So you can call a method called 'name' in the first example because it exists ;) In the second case you would have to write them your self. Because this kind of methods are so boiler plate the @property syntax was added so the programer would not have to write basically the same code for any other variable he/she want's to use :)